# `Realm` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.10`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.8.3`

Tags: ios, swift, realm, cocoapods, xcode12

I tried to update the cocoa pods, but facing an issue while updating(xcode12, macOS Catalina 10.15.5). please help. I have also attached a screenshot of my terminal.
Thanks in advance!!
[image]

Comment: There are a lot of solutions but after we got a similar error, in one case this fixed it `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`. Then the other case was to totall remove cocoapods and then reinstall. So `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` then `gem install cocoapods`

Comment: @Jay I have uninstalled cocoapods and then again tried to install coaoapods, getting the same error

Comment: Try it with brew.  `brew cleanup -d -v ` and then `brew install cocoapods `

Answer (score 27):

I solved the above problem by updating the ruby to the latest version(3.0.0) using the following command in the terminal:

1. Check the version of Ruby installed on your Mac

   ```
   ruby -v
   ```
2. Install the Ruby Version Manager rvm

   ```
   curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
   ```

   Once this command has finished running you need to restart your terminal for rvm to be recognised.
3. Install the latest version of Ruby

   ```
   rvm install ruby-[version]
   ```

   (or)

   ```
   rvm install ruby --latest
   ```
4. Install cocoapods

   ```
   sudo gem install cocoapods

   pod setup
   ```

Comment: @pkamb you are a hero.

Comment: ruby took about 20mn to install - and then the pods worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

Please try to upgrade via brew:

```
brew upgrade cocoapods
```

Comment: "gem which cocoapods" - to check which version of cocoapods is installed.
"sudo gem install cocoapods" - to update cocoapods
"sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/" - if there are several Xcode tools installed

Answer (score 0):

you need to install Xcode Developer Tools first, as mentioned in your error message.
to install Developer Tools, open a Terminal and execute `xcode-select --install` command.

Comment: getting the same error after installing Xcode Developer Tool. Is there any Ruby issue? please refer to the screenshot attached above.

Comment: you could try to install it using `brew`.
1. install `brew`, if you don't have it installed: https://brew.sh/
2. execute `brew install cocoapods`